# Electron not running preload script

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm new to Electron and going through the Quick Start tutorial, and I'm trying to run the preload script that shows the dependecy versions for Chrome, Node, and Electron. For some reason the preload script is not running. I even added a console log to display when the DOM is loaded, and it never shows in the terminal.

`preload.js`

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const replaceText = (selector, text) => {
    const element = document.querySelector(selector);
    if (element) element.innerText = text;
  };

  for (const dependency of ["chrome", "node", "electron"]) {
    replaceText(`${dependency}-version`, process.versions[dependency]);
  }

  console.log("LOADED!");
});
```

`main.js`

```
const path = require("path");
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");

const createWindow = () => {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
    },
  });

  win.loadFile("index.html");
};

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow();

  app.on("activate", () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow();
  });
});

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you getting any error mesages in the main process? Is you `preload.js` script in the same folder as your `main.js` file?